# Room Peristance get all records list size from embedded list

Tags: android

I want to make a query which will get all the sizes from all the records of the list 'times'
example: i have these records

```
1) "20/3/2010" [1,2,3] "reason"
2) "21/3/2010" [1,4,6,7] "reason"
```

the result is

```
1)times.size +   
2)times.size = 7
```

Entity

```
@Entity(tableName = "absence_table")
@TypeConverters(AbsenceTypeConverters::class)
class Absence (
  @PrimaryKey
  var date:String,

  var times:List<String>,
  var reason:String
)
```

Comment: So do you want to get the size of the List times, which is embedded?

Comment: If so, I am afraid you can't do this, as your List is just stored as a String and is converted back into a list inside of your AbsenceTypeConverters

Comment: hm yes that's what i want to do..thank you for answering